# WebContents folder not visible from Eclipse Project View

Tags: java, eclipse

This is very strange, but my WebContents folder has disappeared from the 'Project Explorer' view n Eclipse.

The project is a dynamic web project in Eclipse Helios running on Ubuntu Linux 10.04.

The WebContents folder was visible till sometime back. I am not quite sure what I may have messed up, but this folder is no longer visible from Eclipse. It however, does exist on the file system, and has WEB-INF, META_INF, etc.

Here is a reference to the settings file 'org.eclipse.wst.common.component', which contains a reference to WebContents. I don't think anything has changed in this file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
    <wb-module deploy-name="slides">
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/WebContent"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/test"/>
        <property name="context-root" value="slides"/>
        <property name="java-output-path" value="/slides/build/classes"/>
    </wb-module>
</project-modules>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add it to eclipse again by:

Right click your project, in the context menu choose `Properties` -> `Java Build Path` (Tab Source) and click `Add Folder`.

This usually happens if you don't add `.settings` to your version control.

Comment: Thanks, I just found out the problem. I added it to the build path, which caused it to be hidden from the Project Explorer view.

Comment: Yes, if any folder is added for output then it will not appear in package/project view as A project's output directory isn't relevant to the package view. To see output folder u need to use "Navigator" view.

Comment: @Parag if accept stacker's answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 12):

if you have **Eclipse IDE 2021 or latest version**  and you want to create new Dynamic Web Project but WebContent is not showing in your project.

then follow this steps while creating the project:

1. New-->Dynamic Web Project-->give name to your project--->click on next
   button
2. remove src\main\java folder
3. And type only **src**-->click on next button
4. rename Content directory as WebContent-->select Generate web.xml deployment
   descriptor
5. finish

Comment: does not allow me to do that

Answer (score 0):

I added WebContents to the classpath. That is what made it disappear from the ProjectExplorer window.